# List ist shown in tab view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4.0 to load my tabs. I am using the following code:

```
<div>
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link active" id="all-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#all" role="tab" aria-controls="all" aria-selected="true">All</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" id="categories-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#categories" role="tab" aria-controls="categories" aria-selected="false">Categories</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" id="product-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#product" role="tab" aria-controls="product" aria-selected="false">Product</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
       <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
           <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-tab">...</div>
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="categories" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="categories-tab">...</div>
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="product" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="product-tab">...</div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

However, when I load the page the list items are shown besides the tab.

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: It looks good on [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/h2zgfRi24t) . Are you changing the list style somewhere in your `css`?

Comment: @StaticBeagle Is there a way to hide the list bullets via css? Appreciate your reply!

Comment: Yes, you can use `.nav.nav-tabs {  list-style:none;  }` but `bootstrap` should be doing that by default. There's have got to be something overwriting the default behavior.